# Web Bluetooth: Want to filter on manufacturer data when using navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

I see that Google Chrome has not implemented filtering on manufacturer data. Issue [707635](https://crbug.com/707635), does not seem to have any progress.

The Web Bluetooth specification has an (unstable) spec for filtering manufacturerData when using navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice (https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#example-filter-by-manufacturer-service-data

Does anyone know if there is any progress on this or made this kind of filtering work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following our discussion, I've added support for manufacturer data filter in Web Bluetooth in Chrome 92. See https://crbug.com/707635

Here's an example:

```js
// Filter Bluetooth devices from Google company with manufacturer data bytes
// that start with [0x01, 0x02].
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
  filters: [{
    manufacturerData: [{
      companyIdentifier: 0x00e0,
      dataPrefix: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x02])
    }]
  }],
  optionalServices: ['battery_service'] // Required to access service later.
})
.then(device => { /* … */ })
.catch(error => { console.error(error); });
```

You'll find a sample at https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/manufacturer-data-filter.html and some developer documentation at https://web.dev/bluetooth/#manufacturer-data-filter

Let me know if that works for you ;)

Comment: Is there any chance you could share the website you're working on? I'm just curious ;)

Comment: I am an embedded developer, so someone else in our company does web apps. Right now we do not have a concrete website in progress, but the new features added will increase the probablitity for us to make use of web bluetooth technology in production. When we have such a website, I will make sure to notify you.

Comment: Looking forward to hearing from you then!

Comment: Anything new from your side regarding such a website?

Comment: Sorry, no. Although I informed our developers about the improvements, they are still  somewhat reluctant due to iOS Chrome not supporting web bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome team has NOT made progress on this yet as you've noted. In the mean time, would filtering by device name, device name prefix, or GATT services work out for you?

You can try it with https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/device-info.html.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried those examples. Filtering by device name or prefix will not work for us since our users can rename our devices (and often do). In addition, most of our services are custom, thus needing 128 bit UUID. Advertising 128 bit UUIDs will occupy space for important data we want to advertise. It would help if we can at least filter on manufacturer/vendor ID

Comment: IIUC you don't need `dataPrefix` or `mask`, only manufacturer vendor code ID right?
See https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dictdef-bluetoothdatafilterinit

Comment: FYI I've filed a spec issue at https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/issues/544 to add simple manufacturer id support.

Comment: Thank you again. Filtering on Manufacturer ID will help a lot, while waiting for a possible future filtering on manufacturer data.

Comment: Out of curisoty, how would you filter on manufacturer data?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Which properties (dataPrefix and/or mask) would you use?

Comment: [{manufacturerData: {
    0xYYYY: {dataPrefix: new Uint8Array([0xZZ])},
}}], where YYYY is our manufacturer ID, and ZZ is the first byte after manufacturer ID in manufacturer data. The ZZ in our case will be our product id (we have several BLE devices, each with different product IDs

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67566056/422957.
Feel free to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

1. 'Star' issue [707635](https://crbug.com/707635) to receive updates and signal interest.
2. **If** you have a clear example / business case to share consider adding a comment to help developers understand how to prioritize this work.
3. Chromium is open source, consider contributing or finding a developer to do this work.

Comment: 'Star'd that issue. Thank you.