# Web Bluetooth: Why are most devices "Unknown or unsupported"?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt, web-bluetooth

I am using Web Bluetooth to connect to a device and read the name and battery level.
I got it working but the device I want to connect with is "Unknown or unsupported" but I have no idea why. On requestDevice() I only get my Iphone and a lot of unknown devices.

When I check the bluetooth devices on `chrome://bluetooth-internals` I see a few known devices but not the one I am looking for. I have to guess the right device based on the latest RSSI. This is not user friendly.

Is there a way to fix this? Or can someone explain why almost all the devices are unknown or unsupported.

I am using a Mac. (Incase this matters)

UPDATE @François Beaufort
[image]
A screenshot of the nRF Connect app. In the app the device has a name. I just saw that the device had a name in `bluetooth-internals` too, but it seems like it doesn't advertise its name always.

And it says `Device type: Google` but it isn't a device from Google.

Comment: If you use a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) does the device show up? You don't say what the device is you are trying to find. Is it [advertising](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile/) its `local name`? Is it a BLE device?

Comment: @ukBaz It doesn't show up on nRF Connect. I want to connect with Earbuds with BLE. How can I check if it is advertising its local name? I don't think it is adveritsing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name you're seeing in the bluetooth browser chooser is the human-readable name of the bluetooth device. A bluetooth device may have two different name types: one that the bluetooth device advertises and another that the bluetooth device publishes in its database as its Bluetooth low energy Generic Access Profile (GAP) device name. If a bluetooth device has both types of names, you'll get the GAP device name.

If you're seeing `"Unknown or Unsupported Device (12:34:56:78:9A:BC)"`, it means the bluetooth device didn't advertise its name. In order to reduce the noise in the bluetooth chooser, I'd recommend using other filters such as `"services"` if you notice your bluetooth device advertises some. See full developer documentation at https://web.dev/bluetooth/#services-filter

```js
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ filters: [{ services: ['battery_service'] }] })
.then(device => { /* … */ })
.catch(error => { console.error(error); });
```

Update: You can see advertised services at `chrome://bluetooth-internals/#devices` in the "Services" column in Chrome 93. See https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/commit/49610d372d4d479f43e918d7bbf14537efd2769c

Comment: Thanks! But the column `Services` on the `chrome://bluetooth-internals/#devices` page is empty for all the devices in the list. It is for all `Unknown`. Does that mean the device doesn't advertise any services? When I connect with the device, it has 5 services available.

Comment: Yes. It means your Bluetooth nearby devices don't advertise services sadly. Can you share a screenshot of the NRFConnect app that scans the Bluetooth device you're interested in? I wonder if there are other filters you could use to get it.
See https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en

Comment: I updated the question with a screenshot.

Comment: It seems like a service UUID is advertised for this device `0xFE61`. Would `navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ filters: [{ services: [0xFE61] }] })` work for you?
If not, you may want to use manufacturer data filter (available in Chrome 92 - https://chrome.com/canary) with something like `navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ filters: [{ manufacturerData: [{ companyIdentifier: 0x01DA }] }] })`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67020600/web-bluetooth-want-to-filter-on-manufacturer-data-when-using-navigator-bluetoot/67566056#67566056

Comment: The filter on the services works! Thanks!

Comment: I do think advertised and service UUIDs should be displayed in `about:bluetooth-internals`. They're not today sadly which is a pain as you've seen.
You can star https://crbug.com/1210506 to keep track of the progress.